# what have you done?/ what did you do?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

If I am doing a work on a simulation, and this simulation is working but after some times it does not work anymore and I say that to the colleague.
What should he say between "what have you done?" or "what did you do?"

- I know that "what have you been doing" is wrong because it was not continuous.
- To me, "what have you done?" is the correct auswer but I do not know really...

Comment: There are lots and lots of questions and answers about past tense v. present perfect.  In many cases (including this) both are possible.  The idea that there is one and only one correct tense is because a result of learning English to pass a test. Please take a little time to explore the "related" questions on the right.

Comment: Neither of these are wrong. However, to be honest with you "What have you done?" sounds quite impolite and aggressive in this context, almost an accusation.   Might be better to say "What were you doing when this happened?"

Comment: The use of the present perfect _continuous_ in "what have you been doing" isn't wrong. We use it to say that something is still continuing in the present. Your work on the simulation is still continuing, I think.

Comment: @Old Brixtonian The continuous can also be used when the action has recently stopped but its effects are important in the present, in this case the simulation that isn't working, because of an action done in the recent past.

Comment: @anouk: I think that's present perfect without the continuous isn't it?

Comment: @Old Brixtonian Not necessarily, for example: "she's been drinking wine and now she's drunk" or "I'm sweaty, because I've been jogging". She's stopped drinking but she's drunk now, I've stopped jogging, but I'm sweaty now.

Comment: There seems to be a difference of opinion. These are from the [British Council Learn English site:](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/present-perfect) "We normally use the present perfect continuous to emphasise that something is still continuing in the present"....."the idea of seeing evidence of the recent activity is associated with the present perfect continuous."

Comment: @Old Brixtonian "the idea of seeing evidence of the recent activity is associated with the present perfect continuous."  This is exactly what I mean: a recently completed activity with evidence in the present.

Answer (score 1):

Both are perfectly fine:

> What have you done?
>
> What did you do?

**What have you done** will almost always be interpreted as an accusation that the person has done something wrong.

In both cases, the speaker is aware of what the person has been doing or has done or at least what the outcome was, so the question is somewhat rhetorical.

**What have you been doing** is not grammatically incorrect, it just has a different meaning that doesn't really fit your context. In this case, the speaker probably doesn't know what the person has been doing  and is unaware of anything that has happened as a result. It's not accusatory, it's a question by someone who doesn't know what the person has been doing. It can also be used as a general greeting, similar to "What's up?"

Comment: Could you please explain the different meaning of " what have you been doing" ?

Comment: I modified my answer to include that

Answer (score 0):

What have you done? What did you do? Both are possible. Both the actions have ended.

What have you done?- present perfect tense

What did you do?- simple past tense

But 'What have you been doing' is in the present perfect tense. The action is still continuing. It has not ended.